# jQuery.event.drop using multiple configs

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, drag-and-drop

I'm using jQuery.event.drop by ThreeDubMedia ([here](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drop)) to build a drag and drop application. If i read right, there is only the way to add global options.

I have different usecases for this plugins, requiring different configs.

e.g. In one part of the application, i am using the multi option

```
$.drop({ 
    multi: true
});
```

On the same page, just in another div, i need to disable multi and set mode: true - using a config like that

```
$.drop(
{ 
    mode:true,
    multi: false
});
```

When executing this piece of code, the old config is rewritten and the multi drag and drop won't work anymore - unless i overwrite it again.

Any ideas on how to use multiple configs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Came up with a little "hacky solution".
I'm now using the drag "start" event to replace the config to the currently needed for the drag & drop action.

Something like this:

```
$("#myel").drag("start",function( ev, dd ){

    // Replace config

    $.drop({ 
        multi: true,
        mode: "overlap",
    });

    // ... 
})
```

And on the other drag binding:

```
$("#myel2").drag("start",function( ev, dd ){

    // Replace config

    $.drop({ 
        multi: false,
        mode: true,
    });

    // ... 
})
```

Not very beautiful but at least it works.
If you have other solutions for this, please share!